# Passing environment variables to YARN containers

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

We have a complex environment which compute daily tasks with several technologies: SPARK PY-SPARK Java MapReduce and HIVE.

Recently we integrated a new system which make dynamic resolution for services in runtime. This system updates an environment variable(dynamically) before task is initialize.

There is a library which read to environment variable and do stuff with it(unrelevant). Therefore each task needs this env variable on its executor/mapper/reducer environment.

Our tasks managed by YARN Resource manager.

To Sumup I want to pass YARN env variables which it will expose on all of it's containers (ApplicationMaster and executors/mappers/reducers).

Things I tried so far:

SPARK - I played with :

```
spark-submit --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.KEY=Value
```

This actually expose the env variable to the application master but not on the executors so if a UDF function will try to find it, it will fail.

A possible solution for that is to use:

```
spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]
```

In MapReduce I'm a bit lost I didn't find a way to pass environment variable with

```
hadoop jar
```

The best I can do is to pass the variable on conf file and than expose it using java code. 
To expose it to the mappers/reducers I used:

```
mapreduce.map/reducer.env
```

This approach is not good for because it makes me modify all my MapReduce Jobs

So I decided to approach it through yarn containers. However after couple of days of experimenting I got zero results.
So my question.
Is there a way to manipulate yarn to initialize it's containers with my extra environment variable through spark-submit and hadoop jar

For instance

```
hadoop jar -Dyarn.expose.this.variable=value
```

I also be happy to accept answers if it only solve MapReduce in way that let me expose env variables without altering MapReduce code.

Comment: `hadoop jar -Dvar=${SOME_LOCAL_VAR}` works fine. You then need to get `var` in the code of course

Comment: @cricket_007 This option is not good for me because it only set it in conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you **are** looking for these

- `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env`
- `mapreduce.map.env`
- `mapreduce.reduce.env`

Search for descriptions on https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

Specifically, it says that if you set `-Dmapreduce.map.env='A=foo', then it will set A environment variable to "foo"`

And those will get passed to YARN containers.

> This approach is not good for because it makes me modify all my MapReduce Jobs

I'm sure I understand how you'd avoid altering code otherwise. Some library needs to be modified to read the environment or otherwise defined properties

> Recently we integrated a new system which make dynamic resolution for services in runtime

I think I've seen dynamic configurations setup with Zookeeper/Consul/Etcd; but I've not seen YARN environment specific things outside of Docker container labels, for example

Comment: But where do I pass it? How I control it in run time? where do I control this variables?

Comment: Im looking for this. hadoop jar myJob.jar -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.env.KEY=VALUE changing XML is not dynamic

Comment: What do you mean XML? In Oozie? Otherwise, those `-D` flags are the only way I know of

Comment: I think I missing something I can use yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env with -D how ?can you write an example? because I can't manage to use it..

Comment: I mean it's a syntax problem I can find how I can set an environment variable using mapreduce.map.env

Comment: `-Dmapreduce.map.env='A=foo'` will set `A` environment variable to `"foo"`

Comment: Another small question maybe you should add it to the answer. Using "-Dmapreduce.map.env='A=foo'" will override all the env which I added ? or it will add it to the env already there?  Let's say I want to add two evn variables         -Dmapreduce.map.env='A=foo -Dmapreduce.map.env='B=foo2                          I this works? or I will have only one en variable B=foo2